# Hanging CruiseControl

Tags: cruisecontrol

Here is the problem.
Our cruisecontrol setup for continuous integration(V2.5 configured to work with subversion) works just fine - except on the days we need it most!
Here is what I mean. I inherited the configuration from a former collegue, but as far as i can tell, the configuration has worked just fine for years now. But on certain days when the activities are intense, with more checkins and more builds in rapid succession, cruise seems to hang without a reason. 
The build results page shows a blank blue screen all of a sudden and the builds thereoff dont get triggered until I go and restart the cruise service.

This also means that intermittent checkins dont trigger builds.

Has anyone faced this problem before? I am considering upgrading to a new version but want to know what others think. Any known issues? resolutions at hand?

Appreciate any help - I'd like to ensure I stay alive for a long time to come (The coders are getting more and more annoyed with every passing day with this cranky behavior).

And I dont really like switching tools unless I have good reason to discard the one that is already in place.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues in 2.5 that could cause it to stop working, try the jstack tool too see what the java threads are up to, see what code they are stuck in.

It could be something similer to this issue http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CC-527

You would probably be quite well off looking at upgrading it, or migrating to hudson / teamcity